# Chart.js - ReferenceErrore : Chart is not defnied

Tags: lightning, community, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js inside a Lightning Community app and I'm having trouble creating a simple chart. Here's my script declaration (note that the *moment.min.js* is required for the Chart.js to work) :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
    $Resource.BundleResources + '/BundleResources/js/moment.min.js',
    $Resource.BundleResources + '/BundleResources/js/Chart.min.js')}" 
      afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}"/>
```

and here's my rendere javascript file :

```
afterRender : function(component, helper)
{
    this.superAfterRender();

    try
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('networkChart');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // below is the standard Chart.js example found in their documentation
        var youpi = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['label1', '2', 'et 3'],
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }catch(e){
        helper.logError('catched error : ' + e);
    }
}
```

and below is the error the console is giving me :

```
catched error : ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

My Chart.min.js is well included, no error on this side. Does anybody knows where I failed ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`afterRender` will be called before `ltng:require` loads the required scripts. You need to wait until the `afterScriptsLoaded` method is called (in other words, your `init` method).